Flutter installation issues

I am struggling with these problems during flutter installation.
If someone know how to fix it, I will be grateful.
Thanks in advance !
I tried to install all things 2-3 times and it still doesn't work.
What could be the reason ?

have you tried to run the following command to fix the android issues? flutter doctor --android-licenses
It's hard to guess, but I would restart my device.

Cocoapods doesn't get installed automatically, you need to install it using terminal so if you google search it then you will be able to find a doc on how to install cocoapods on mac.

1st issue is related to Android toolchain. Simply run flutter doctor --android-licenses & accept all licences.
2nd one is saying that you haven't installed Cocoapods. Install homebrew and run brew install cocoapods.
